# Installing ender.js on windows - npm WARN gzip@0.1.0

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, npm, ender

I need help with [Ender-js](http://ender.no.de/) installation.
Trying to set it up on my machine (Windows XP).

First I've installed node-js v0.6.6 & downloaded (&unzipped) the latest NPM - 1.1.0-beta-7.
As per "[Fancy Windows Install](http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html)"

Then I run -

> npm install ender -g

And get this warning -
npm WARN gzip@0.1.0 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']
I can call "ender help" from the commandline for example.

But trying to build something with ender (in this case jeesh) fails:

> ender build jeesh
>   installing packages: "ender-js jeesh"...
>   this can take a minute...
>   something went wrong trying to load npm!

Thanks a lot in advance!